# jQuery add vertical scroll bar based on the height of the window

Tags: jquery

I have 30 result set and I want to add dynamic vertical scroll bar based on the mobile or browser height using jQuery i.e if the results are more.

```
<div class="banklist">
    <h1>Pay using Netbanking</h1>
    <input name="" type="text" class="textbox" id="filter" onkeyup="this.setAttribute('value', this.value);" value="">
    <div class="list">
       <img src="images/logo_citi.gif" class="img">Citibank Online                            
    </div>
    <div class="list">
       <img src="images/logo_hdfc.gif" class="img">HDFC Bank
    </div>
    <div class="list">
       <img src="images/logo_hdfc.gif" class="img">ICICI Bank
    </div>
    <div class="list">
       <img src="images/logo_hdfc.gif" class="img">Andhra Bank
    </div>
    ...............
    ...............
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

//check for height on any mobile devices the answer lies within adding the css overflow-y axis same is adding scroll on x axis "overflow-x"

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

```
   if($('.banklist').height() > 120){
        $('.banklist').css('overflow-y','scroll');    
    }
```

});

Answer (score 0):

try to get the body height. try this

```
 var BodyHeight = 0, body = window.document.body
 if (window.innerHeight) {
        BodyHeight = window.innerHeight;
    }
    else if (body.parentElement.clientHeight) {
        BodyHeight = body.parentElement.clientHeight;
    }
    else if (body && body.clientHeight) {
        BodyHeight = body.clientHeight;
    }
```